Attempt to re-open an already closed object: SQLiteDatabase error when closing db instances after each function
I want to ensure that db instances are closed to avoid memory leaks but when I add readDB.close()/writeDB.close()/both to the end of each function, most work fine but one function reports it is attempting to reopen a closed instance of writeDB despite being the function being completely separate.
This is the function:
fun updateEditProfile(editProfileData : List<String>) {
        val writeDB = writableDatabase

        val selection = "$AccountUUID = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(getUUID())

        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(AccountBIO, editProfileData[0])
            put(AccountAGEPRIVACY, editProfileData[1])
            put(AccountDISTANCEPRIVACY, editProfileData[2])
        }

        writeDB.update(AccountTABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs)
    }


It is a standalone function in the class and not contained within another.
I have tried to remove writeDB.close() from some functions running at a similar time but it still returns the error. The DB function is called in the onStop() of the activity.
The activity has an instance of the DB helper class that is used throughout val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this).
I'm looking for advice on the proper way to manage db instances so that resources aren't wasted but this reopening error won't occur at all.
EDIT - After some more testing, the error is occurring consistently whenever the activity is stopped and is not intermittent.

What would prevent you from doing a using statement to close it that way? In my experience that prevents errors.

Issue not related to db.close(), issue was related to running DB function 2 inside DB function 1, issue resolved by fixing nesting
